# How to solve $y'=(x+y)^n + 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problem with solving this type of differential equations:

$y'=(x+y)^5+2, \ \ \ y'=(x+y)^{-1}-1$, etc. Here $y$ is a function of $x$.

Could you tell me how to solve it?

I can't find this type of equations anywhere, and frankly - I don't even know how to look for them.

I was thinking of putting $u(x)=\frac{1}{x+y}$, then $y'(x)= \frac{u'(x)}{u(x)^2}-1$. But the result isn't the same as in Wolfram.
I get $\frac{u'}{u^2}-1=u-1$  and $u'=u^3$ and $u = +/- \sqrt{\frac{1}{-2(x-c)}}, \ c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The substitution $x+y=u$ is natural. Then it is just integration.

Comment: Aha. Then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the post above I'm solving the second one.

Comment: Thanks, but there should be $u'-1=\frac{1}{u}-1$, shouldn't there? $u(x)=y(x)+x, \ y(x)=u(x)-x, \ y'(x)=u'(x)-1$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still do not see why there is $1+u'$ on the left side of the first equation in your comment...

Comment: Ok. Could you solve for example $y'=(x+y)^6+3$?

Comment: I see. How about $y'=(x+y)^3+1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, we solve the DE $y'=\frac{1}{x+y}-1$.

Let $x+y=z$. Then $1+y'=z'$, so $y'=z'-1$. Then our equation can be rewritten as $z'-1=\frac{1}{z}-1$, which simplifies to $zz'=1$. Integrate. We get $\frac{z^2}{2}=x+C$, and we are nearly finished.

The example $y'=(x+y)^3+1$ mentioned in a comment is much harder. (By the way, $y'=(x+y)^3-1$, by contrast, is straightforward.)

The problem is the integration. If we make the substitution $x+y=z$, we get $1+y'=z'$ and therefore the equation becomes $z'-1=z^3+1$. This simplifies to $\frac{z'}{z^3+2}=1$.

Now we need to find an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{z^3+2}$. This is somewhat painful. We can factor $z^3+2$ as $(z+2^{1/3})(z^2-2^{1/3}z+2^{2/3})$, then use partial fractions. After a fair while we end up with a logarithm and an arctan. And then we will not be able to find an *explicit* formula for $z$ in terms of $x$.